# Prototype.js: Showing the next hidden div

Tags: prototypejs

How do I show a hidden adjacent div on Prototype.js? Here is my current code:

```
<button id="checkAnswer" onclick="checkAnswer2()">Check Answer</button>
<p class="feedback">Feedback:</p>
```

Script:

```
function checkAnswer2 () {
    $('checkAnswer').next().show();        
}
```

Comment: Do you mean adjacent paragraph instead of div?  The paragraph doesn't appear to be hidden (no style="display:none").  If it is hidden via css stylesheet show() won't work.

Comment: Also, if you put the ID in the function, you’re going to have to make a new function for each question/answer pair. How about this:

    ```<button class=“checkAnswer”>Check Answer</button>
    <p class=“feedback”>Feedback:</p>

    $$(‘.feedback’).invoke(‘hide’);
    $(document).on(‘click’, ‘.checkAnswer’, function(evt, elm){
      elm.next(‘p’).show();
    });```

Comment: Thank you T.Gibbons! I didn't know that it affects CSS declaration to Prototype.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put the ID in the function, you’re going to have to make a new function for each question/answer pair. How about this:

```
<button class=“checkAnswer”>Check Answer</button>
<p class=“feedback”>Feedback:</p>
```

script

```
$$('.feedback').invoke('hide');
$(document).on('click', '.checkAnswer', function(evt, elm){
  elm.next('p').show();
});
```

Now you can repeat as many of these as you want on the page, and each button will always manage whatever p follows it.

Comment: Thank you Walter, it's quite difficult to look for tutorials for Prototype as opposed to JQuery.